# I am looking to find the average of the last 6 corresponding weekdays in a dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a cash forecast using the average of the last 6 days that correspond to a particular weekday.

My dataset is formatted as such:
Row 1: Headers
Column A: Date
Column F: Cash position
Column G: Day of week

After column G is filtered to a specific day (i.e. Monday), I'd like to extract the last 6 visible values in columns A & F. Using column A as an example, here is my current failed code:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A460:A485").Select
Range("A485").Activate
```

The range on line 3 was coded from shift-clicking upwards 5x from the bottom of the data set. I'm looking to copy the data within this range, while not defining what the range is.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What are you asking?  If it is, "How to I get from here to there?", then it is too broad a question for this site.

Comment: Again there is no question in that comment, only a statement of wants.  This is a question/answer site.  And, the question should be about a specific issue not a broad "please help" request.

Comment: Some ideas: Using Excel Formulas, you can check the weekday with `WEEKDAY`. Monday is 2, so if `WEEKDAY(YourDate) = 2` then it is a monday. In VBA you can do `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(YourDate) = vbMonday Then`. And then loop until you find 6 of them.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. My current dataset is from Row 2 to Row 488, with Row 1 containing the headers. After filtering column G to the day of the week, I'd like to obtain the last 6 data points in column A.

In this example, the last six data points of the filtered dataset are located in cells: A460, A465, A470, A475, A480, & A485. I'd like my macro to copy these six data points and paste them onto another sheet.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this is a variable range, with a new data point being added each day. 

I hope this helps.

Comment: Once again you state a list of wants and do not ask a specific question.  That is not what this site is about.

Comment: I'm new to macros and have been self-learning via this website & others. Is: "How do I create a macro code to copy the last 6 rows of a filtered dataset" not a specific question? If not, I'll see myself out.

Comment: Which column has the date in it ?

Comment: It is not specific.  Questions like, "How do I find the last row? Here is how I tried but failed" is an example of a specific question.  You need to break down each step and search that step, then try to piece it all together.  When it errors come back and ask a specific question with a [mcve] and we will gladly help overcome the specific problem.

Comment: Column A has the date. Column G is a formula that pulls in the specific weekday. and Column F has the cash position for the day. So my goal is to copy/paste the last 6 visible cells in columns A & F, based off of the column G filter.

Comment: Sure thing, here is a brief example of my failed code.
Sub ExampleDelete()
'
' ExampleDelete Macro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A460:A485").Select
    Range("A485").Activate
End Sub

The solution that I am seeking would allow me to copy the visible data from A460 through A485 without defining said range, as the visible data will change daily.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include that code. comments are not meant to contain code.

Comment: This has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

Scan up the sheet for 6 dates that are mondays and fill an array. Then dump the array to the other sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Last6Mon()
    Dim ar(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, r As Long
    i = 6
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(.Cells(r, "A")) = vbMonday Then
                ar(i, 1) = .Cells(r, "A") ' date
                ar(i, 2) = .Cells(r, "F") ' cash posn
                i = i - 1
                If i = 0 Then Exit For
            End If
         Next
         'another worksheet
         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B7") = ar
    End With
End Sub
```